# open save dialog box in browser to save file comes from server in struts2

Tags: javascript, jquery, struts2, browser

In my strut2 base web application I have generate xls on server and send back to user to save with following code

```
 outputStream  = response.getOutputStream();
 response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");
 response.setHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment; filename=sampleName.xls");
```

when this response goes to client browser it open as download popup but i want it open as save dialog so that user can able to save it. is it possible. if yes how ?

Comment: The browser gives a dialog that says open or save, that is how it works.

Comment: yes it gives but i want save as dialog box like when we save file  from file menu

Comment: @SwapnilSonawane why you playing with Response object when S2 provides a clean and efficient way for this.[stream-result](http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/stream-result.html).Additinaly the save as dialogue box if i remember correct can be there by setting correct mime-type

Comment: @UmeshAwasthi yes I tried with type='stream' in xml file then also it open as download and i also i want to use response.getoutputStream to create excel file without saving it on server

Comment: @SwapnilSonawane:i am not sure S2 has any relation how the dialogue box open and its entirely client side perspective. Additionally i am not sure what you mean by not saving the file on server, as even stream result will open a stream and transfer the content close it and will do clean up work for you same as being done by you

Comment: @UmeshAwasthi yes I quess s2 has no relation with dialog box.but any addition paramater need to set in response or any thing addition done on client side

Comment: @SwapnilSonawane: i don't remember any such parameters

Comment: There is no struts2 solution for what you ask. If you want to change the behaviour of the client then you'll need to modify the browser in someway. This is only practical if you have an Intranet application where you have control over the desktops and can enforce your plugin/configuration settings. If someone modified the default behaviour to achieve what you want, I as a user would be quite annoyed due to the need to download content (which I might not need) before viewing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is: There is no solution for the requirements given (solution must be implemented client side - configuration change in mime handling on client required). PS: Someone updating my desktop (in a company) to disable preview before the option to save would greatly annoy me.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check out OpenSave:

http://www.gieson.com/Library/projects/utilities/opensave/

Looks like you can use AJAX to go from server to client to dialog?